# Removing some individuals from a data.frame

Tags: r, subset

Lets say I have these data:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"),10),
    ValueOne = rnorm(50),
    ValueTwo = rnorm(50))
head(data)
```

Where there are 50 observations of two different values from 5 individuals (AAA - EEE).

I want to subset the example data to exclude Inds "AAA","BBB"and "EEE" and have named them to an new object.

```
RemoveInds <- c("AAA","BBB","EEE")
```

How would I create a new `data.frame` that excludes these individuals and does so using the object `RemoveInds`?

What am I missing here?

```
newData <- data[data$IndID != RemoveInds,]
newData <- subset[data, data$IndID != RemoveInds]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks!  very helpful.  Post as answer...

Comment: You could also use `grepl` (though in this case its a bit clumsy) `data[!grepl(paste(RemoveInds, collapse = "|"), data$IndID), ]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- `grepl` is terribly dangerous here, because it treats its first argument as a regular expression rather than as a character string to be matched exactly. Compare e.g. `grepl("a", "bat")` and `"a" %in% "bat"` -- they're not doing the same thing at all.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I know that. But you are right, I should have mention that. I only gave an alternative solution that works on *the provided data set*.

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- And I should have made clearer that I was only adding the comment for the benefit of newer R users who might otherwise see your suggestion and say "hey, that's a cool alternative to `%in%`". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
newdata<- data[!data$IndID %in% RemoveInds, ]
```